# How to withdraw Euros from an ATM in Warsaw?

Tags: europe, money, poland

I am a tourist in Warsaw, Poland. I want to withdraw some Euros. Could anybody suggest how I do that, as I have a Euro card and want to avoid conversion charges.

Comment: Why do you want Euros in Poland? They're not used there!

Comment: First of all, thnx for reply
I need to give it to someone going to other states of Europe.

Comment: Not sure if ICE (International Currency Exchange) operate any ATMs in Poland (they would most probably be in airports or large train stations). Those they operate in London deliver both GBP and EUR.

Comment: Transfer money into their bank account?

Comment: I have already searched at Chopin Airport but didn't found any EURO dispenser, yeah can look in at Railway Stations. 

Thnx

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of EuroNet ATMs in Warsaw, where you can withdraw Euros.

Check [this link](http://www.euronetpolska.pl/p,282,_wyplata_eur__gbp__nok_lub_sek.html). There is some info in English there. You can also search for the ATMs there.

Here is [the map](http://www.euronetpolska.pl/index.php?m=maps&m_2=results&id=254&district_id=0&city_id=2&street_id=0&pokaz=on&service%5B%5D=8).

Comment: Yeah its there but only works for cards issued in Poland and settled in PLN. Not for a foreigner.

Comment: That is true .. uhh can't seem to find any info about other solutions. You can try going to any bank and asking for help - maybe they can withdraw EUR for you with a little provision ? I dont think there is any other way to do that without paying extra fee...

Comment: The easiest option would probably withdrawing PLN and then exchanging the cash for EUR. The rates should be not worse those offered by such ATMs (though I don't know the Polish situation specifically).

Comment: I already have EURO Card, this way it would be EUR>PLN>EUR Double the conversion charges.

Comment: @Avi what did you do? I am in a similar situation.

Answer (score -1):

As you (appear to) live in the Eurozone, you could ask a friend there to post you Euros to your Polish hotel. You then repay them on your return, or wire the money to them before hand.